# Insert row in the middle of the table with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to insert a row at the beginning of the table after the head of the table. The method prepend() didn't help me so much because is inserting before the head and the methods after and before are also not helping me.
This my table:

```
<table id="info_table" data-striped="true">
            <tr class="prima">
               <td>Id</td>
               <td>Person</td>
               <td>Time</td>
               <td>Instructions</td>
               <td>Von</td>
               <td>Bis</td>
           </tr>
    </table>
```

I insert a row `<tr>` and after this, my second row should be directly after the head of the table.

```
var tds = '<tr id="tr" class="data">';
tds += '<td><select></select></td>';        
tds += '<td>'+name+'</td>';
tds += '<td>+time+</td>';
tds += '<td><input type="text" value=""></td>';
tds += '<td></td>';
tds += '<td></td>';
tds += '</tr>';

$("#info_table").append(tds);
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("#info_table tr:first").after(tds); // as your first tr is head then it'll append after that
```

Comment: Excellent! Thx very much! The idea is in general the same like @Norlihazmey Ghazali but more general and practical, I mean exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

if you want to insert in the `middle` try `after` with `eq(index)`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var name="some body";
 $("#info_table > tr").length;//> tbody
var tds = '<tr id="tr" class="data">';
tds += '<td><select></select></td>';        
tds += '<td>'+name+'</td>';
tds += '<td>+time+</td>';
tds += '<td><input type="text" value=""></td>';
tds += '<td></td>';
tds += '<td></td>';
tds += '</tr>';
$('#info_table > tbody > tr').eq(parseInt($("#info_table > tbody > tr").length/2)-1).after(tds);
});

</script>

 <table id="info_table" data-striped="true">
    <tr class="prima">
       <td>Id</td>
       <td>Person</td>
       <td>Time</td>
       <td>Instructions</td>
       <td>Von</td>
       <td>Bis</td>
   </tr>
      <tr class="prima">
       <td>Id</td>
       <td>Person</td>
       <td>Time</td>
       <td>Instructions</td>
       <td>Von</td>
       <td>Bis</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here try this :

```
// #info_table tr:eq(0) --> first table row(head)
$(tds).insertAfter('#info_table tr:eq(0)');
```